# why use reloadRows in beginUpdates and endUpdates

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

in many other posting, they use only reloadRows between beginUpdates and endUpdates.

like this

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

but when i use this way and use only reloadRows without beginUpdates and endUpdates,
i dont know any difference.

why use reloadRows in beginUpdates and endUpdates??

Comment: Just as you said. Using it for a single operation has no benefit. It's for multiple insert/delete/move operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a bad practice which doesn't *hurt*.

There is no reason at all.

`beginUpdates() / endUpdates()` are useful for **multiple simultaneous** `insert/delete/move` operations.

The methods have no effect for a single operation and are completely useless for calling `reloadRows`

Comment: so when i use only reloadRows, just use without begins and ends ??

Comment: Yes, exactly 

Comment: @vadian - picture an app where you're ordering up many changes to the table from many different places for many different reasons (bad practice, but it can happen).  in these cases the (a) altering the data array and (b) actually altering the table view, of course (a)-(b) must happen atomically with nothing in between.  consider your "other" processes that perhaps add/delete/etc - each of those would need begin/end pairs as usual.  imo your call which uses only reloadRows, in fact, needs a begin/end pair or else it can step on the others.